# Three random points in a cube

Tags: probability, geometry

Select three points $A$, $B$, and $C$ randomly from a uniform distribution in a cube.  What is the probability that $C$ is inside the sphere whose diameter is $AB$?

This problem might be pretty messy to solve, possibly even more so than the average length of a line segment in a cube problem, but it is still a good problem.  It is related to finding the bounding sphere of four random points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I was somewhat surprised how rarely the circumsphere of the four random points (as a tetrahedron) is the bounding sphere of the points.  Usually, the bounding sphere is determined by only three of the points.  And sometimes it is determined by only two of them.

Comment: This is the same as the probability that $\angle ACB>90^\circ$, or that $\vec c.\vec c+\vec a.\vec b<\vec a.\vec c+\vec b.\vec c$

Comment: @Michael I believe you mean $\geq 90^{\circ}$ to include points on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: @DylanSp the surface of the sphere has zero volume and does not contribute to the result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: (1) What is that probability for uniform $C$ and *fixed* $A$ and $B$? (2) Integrate that result over all $A$ and $B.$